# JSON decode crashing

Tags: php, json

I'm retrieving a text from rich text area and trying to put in a json.
I have a json like this:

```
{"content":"<p>Mauritian politics is vibrant and characterised by several problems. 
Some of them are coalition...","title":"sdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd","interestId":"11","commentType":"Post"}
```

Now, when I'm trying to parse the above json in php, it is failing giving me a blank json.

I know what the problem is, the problem is that the space after the 'several problems.' Because I parse this, it is ok

```
{"content":"<p>Mauritian politics is vibrant and characterised by severak problems.Some of them are coalition...","title":"sdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd","interestId":"11","commentType":"Post"}
```

Comment: That is not a space, it is a carriage return, remove it from the string and you should be fine. use nl2br() if you want to keep the extra line.

Answer (score 0):

json_decode() is failing because of the new line. To embed new lines into JSON, use "\n". eg:

```
<?php
$a = 'test
test
cheese';

echo json_encode(array($a));
?>
```

This outputs:

```
["test\ntest\ncheese"]
```

Comment: The content is from HTML, for e.g. the user may copy a whole page and paste it in a rich text area. Then what i do is i get the HTML, build a json for it and send it to REST API where it will be saved as a user comment

Comment: In that case I would suggest that instead of manually building the JSON, use json_encode() on a PHP array as in the example above. That way you will be sure that you'll have valid JSON.